# Javascript new Date(string) returns one day behind

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, constructor

I wrote `new Date("2014-10-31")` in my Chrome console, and I got back `Thu Oct 30 2014 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`

What gives? Why is it Oct 30? Shouldn't it be Oct 31?

Comment: the constructor takes UTC.

Comment: see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I upvoted this; the downvote was possibly due to a lack of research?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's actually correct. The `Date` object's constructor takes a UTC datetime.
See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse